# UploadHandle always returning no files, even after an attempt to upload a file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file, however, it always seems to never send the file to the server, even though there's no error or fail being reported by file upload.

I've attempted to use chunking, file sizes, and constantly checking the folder on my server to see if it's available or not.

> "File isn't on server..."

is now the message box that always returns, and **/inf/uploadhandle/index.php**
 does exist, as I'm able to use that direct link in my browser to always return

```
{"files":[]}
```

**Html**

```
<form action="/inf/fileuploadxx.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>Upload: </h2>
<input type="file" id="fileuploadx" name="filex" data-url="/inf/uploadhandle/index.php">
<br>
<div id="progressfile" style="width:100%; background:black;display:none;";>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%; height: 18px; background: green;}">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="progressfiletext">
</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<h2 id="waitsubmit">waiting for approved file...</h2>
<input id="truesubmit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Continue" name="submit" style="align-self:center;display:none;">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileuploadx').fileupload({
        url: '/inf/uploadhandle/index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload:true,
        maxNumberOfFiles:1,
        //maxFileSize: 1200000000, // 120 MB
        //maxChunkSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
        add: function (e, data) {
            $("#fileuploadx").css('display','none');
            $("#progressfile").show();
            $("#progressfiletext").text("Uploading...");

            data.submit();
            console.log("uploading request! ");
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $("#waitsubmit").hide();
            $("#truesubmit").show();
            var x=0;
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $("#progressfiletext").text(file.name);
                x++;
            });
            if (x==0){
                $("#progressfiletext").text("File isn't on server...");
                $("#progressfile .bar").css('background','red');
            }
            console.log("upload pass!");
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progressfile .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
            if (progress > 99) {
                $("#progressfiletext").text("Pushing file through Cloudflare, may take a little bit more.");
            }
            $("#progressfiletext").text("Uploading... ("+progress + '%'+")");
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            console.log("fail...");
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
            $("#progressfiletext").text("Failed upload.");
            $("#progressfile .bar").css('background','red');
        },
        error: function (e, data) {
            console.log("error....");
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
            $("#progressfiletext").text("Failed upload.");
            $("#progressfile .bar").css('background','red');
        }
    });
    $('#fileuploadx').bind('fileuploadprocessfail', function (e, data) {
        alert(data.files[data.index].error);
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit:**
I've added the following PHP to /inf/fileuploadxx.php to

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
echo "<br>type?:" . $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
echo "<br>method:" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

echo '<br><br><br><br>';
if($_POST) {
    $allowed = array('png');

    if(isset($_FILES['filex']) && $_FILES['filex']['error'] == 0){

        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['filex']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
            echo 'bad extension error ;(';
        }

        //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filex']['tmp_name'], "/secure/" . $extension)){
            echo 'yaaaaaaaaaaay';
        //}
        //echo 'upload error ;( end';
    } else {
        echo 'upload error ;( fileerror';
        echo '<br>xxx>' . isset($_FILES['filex']);
        echo '<br>yyy>' . $_FILES['filex']['error'];
    }
} else {
    echo 'nopost';
}
```

with the output being

> upload error ;( fileerror
>
> xxx>1
>
> yyy>4

Comment: perhaps you need to show the code on the server side? the side that accepts the file and puts it where it needs to go? have you checked the browser **developer** tools console for errors? what are they?

Comment: There's no errors in the developer console, and I'm pulling the exact fresh server-sided PHP file from GitHub, that has no edits. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: what about the network tab - does it show the upload in progress?

Comment: It does show that /inf/uploadhandle/index.php is pending while the progress bar speeds to 100%, takes a few seconds (cloudflare?), and then the red error `"File isn't on server..."`, that was made in the javascript.